# How do I move the cursor back after completing yas-choose-value?

Tags: yasnippet

I have a snippet set like so:

```js
import React from 'react'

const ${1:$$(file-name-base)} = ( ${2:$$(yas-choose-value '("\{ \}" "props"))} ) => {
  return (
    $0
)
}

export default $1
```

If I choose `{}`, the cursor moves to the right of it. After choosing `{}`, how do I place the cursor between the brackets, i.e `{_}`?

---

An example of a completed snippet:

```js
import React from 'react'

const Notification = ({ message }) => {
  return (
    <div className='error'>
      {message}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Notification
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough context to answer this.  Can you show how you expect the sinppet to expand.  Also why are you using `yas-choose-value` with only one list item?

Comment: @ocodo I forgot to add it back. I use the snippet to create an es6 module from a newly created file. I added an example of a completed one above.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `yas-choose-value` doesn't provide any additional magic to move your cursor into the braces.

The simplest and most flexible way to achieve what you want,  is to use stacked expansion. In other words, another snippet expand while you're expanding this one, making it just `$2`

#### `yas/triggers-in-field`

This variable, when set to `t` will do just that, type the next snippet trigger and when it's done, you'll be returned to the original snippet.  In your case at `$0`.